# C# Is cloning outside the lock thread safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, object, thread-safety

Is it thread safe to use this method:

```
private Dictionary<int,myObject> myDict = new Dictionary<int,myObject>();
private static object _syncRoot = new object();
void updateDict(int i)
{
    myObject obj = null;
    lock(_syncRoot)
    {
         myDict.TryGetValue(i, out obj);
    }
    if(obj==null) obj = new myObject();
    else
    {
       obj = DeepClone(obj);
    }
    //perform operations on obj
    lock(_syncRoot)
    {
        myDict[i] = obj;
    }
}
```

I am asking because although moving deep cloning inside the first lock will definitely make it thread safe, but it being a big object the cloning will lead to slower execution due to larger thread wait time.

The dictionary is never modified outside of this method.

Comment: You should not lock on the resource itself but use a separate constant object.

Comment: Synchronization is all about creating artificial bottlenecks. And hoping they do not result in (too much) Multithreading slowdown. Nope, a clone will not be save from race conditions if done outside of a lock. So you will not get around that tradeoff. But as Fildor said, it is customary to create a private mutex object olock on. That way there is no danger of deadlocks because someone else tried to aquire a lock on the instance behind "myDict".

Comment: So, two threads queue and take turns to enter the first lock, with the same `i` value. They both get a reference to the same object. They both clone the object. They both make changes to `obj`, which again those are both referring to the same single object. Is that safe? Who knows? Then, oddly, they take a lock the second time and reassign the same reference back into the dictionary. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I'm almost certain that whatever it is, this code isn't the solution.

Comment: If it's possible to make `myObject` immutable, then you would not have these problems. As it stands, however, another thread could mutate `myObject` just after you leave the lock and before (or during) the clone operation.

Comment: @MatthewWatson The way it is implemented right now, I don't see how making myObject immutable would help. Because you would basically do the same thing: Obtain the instance, create a mutated clone, write back. Am I missing something? You'd still have to make the mutation of `myDict` atomic.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If two threads are updating the variable at the same time having updated myObj from either is okay as long as there is no exception thrown.

Comment: @RameshVerma But it would not be deterministic. You wouldn't be able to tell which thread's changes will "win". And only one of them will persist. The other one will be thrown away. Is that _really_ what you want?

Comment: @Fildor Ideally, I would want the changes from both but if it comes to a trade-off between saving time and having all the changes, I will prefer to save time in this scenario.

Comment: "Thread safe" is a rather meaningless term these days, it depends entirely on how *you* want it to behave.

Comment: In that case I'd make it a "tryUpdate" and drop out returning "false" if the same `i` is already being processed. That introduces a little overhead, though. But if cloning and mutating is really expensive, then it would be faster on the whole. If collisions are frequent, that is. Introducing overhead when you have a very low probability of collisions will reduce performance ...

Comment: Why don't you use ConcurrentDictionary and then TryUpdate as documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryupdate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.1

Comment: If cloning the objects can be done in parallel with other reads from the dictionary and other cloning operations, you should lock the cloning process per-object, and not globally.

Comment: @Fildor The reason why I asked it here is that collisions are very infrequent and I couldn't get to know if it would ever throw an exception in a collision situation through testing.

Comment: @Fildor If an object is immutable, it is not possible for it to change state while a thread is making a mutated copy of it, so threading issues would not be a problem for that part. If it's a reference type, then assigning the mutated version to an array element (overwriting the previous) is also an atomic operation - so the entire update operation would be atomic. If, however, you want to make sure that the value in the array hasn't changed between reading and updating, you could use `Interlocked.CompareExchange()` to retry the operation if it was changed by another thread.

Comment: It is impossible to answer meaningfully without seeing the source code of `myObject`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson exactly that's what I meant. You have to make sure, the Dictionary entry has not been changed since reading to make it safe from A to Z. That part is independend of the immutability of myObject.

Comment: @Fildor Agreed, there are two parts to this - however from the OP's comment `"If two threads are updating the variable at the same time having updated myObj from either is okay as long as there is no exception thrown."` it looks like that would be sufficient. (If it was not, I now think that a `ConcurrentDictionary` would be a better choice than messing around with `Interlocked.CompareExchange()`.